# A unidade de medida "em" muda em cada dispositivo?

Tags: html, css, semântica

Quando coloco como unidade "1em" num "font-size" para um desktop por exemplo, irá ficar 15px por padrão já do navegador. Mas o "em" vale um tamanho menor para um dispositivo mobile por exemplo, certo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EM é uma unidade de medida tipográfica. 
Seu nome está relacionada com a letra “M”, onde o tamanho base dessa unidade deriva da largura da letra M em maiúscula. Dizem que 1em equivale aproximadamente 16 pontos.

O problema de utilizar fonts em EM é que elas são variáveis como a porcentagem. Diferentemente da utilização de pixels, temos de calculcar as nossas unidades no projeto.

> target ÷ context = result

Um exemplo: imagine um título, H1, cujo seu tamanho de texto seja 20px.

**CSS EXEMPLO ORIGINAL**

```
       body {
         font: normal 100% verdana, arial, tahoma, sans-serif;
       }    
       div {
            font: 30px verdana, arial, tahoma, sans-serif;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 20px;
        }

        p {
            font-size: 12px;
        }
```

Então o target (que é o elemento que queremos modificar) é 20px. Nesse caso o BODY é o pai do nosso H1. Logo, o valor da font do body é o context (contexto), que como já dissemos tem o valor padrão de 16px. **Logo 20 ÷ 16 = 1.25**.

Imagine que quer fazer um site mobile ou um site para grandes telas. 
Em vez de mudar as fonts de cada elemento, pode simplesmente muda o valor da font do target, ou seja, **do body**!

**CSS EXEMPLO em EM**

```
 body {font: 100% verdana, arial, tahoma, sans-serif;}

    div {
        font-size: 1.88em;
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 0.67em;
    }

    p {
        font-size: 0.4em;
    }
```

**div: 30/16 = 1.88 

h1:  20/30 = 0.67 pois está em relação à div

P:   12/30 = 0.4  pois está em relação à div** 


Mudando o valor de porcentagem da font do body, consegue mudar proporcionalmente a font de todos os outros elementos.

Mas é bastante aborrecido ficar calculado o valor do target e do context para cada um dos elementos. 
Então foi criada outra unidade de medida chamada **REM**
A **REM** sempre terá o valor de contexto do body

Os valores do nosso exemplo acima ficaria assim se referenciando pelo **body** e **não pelo DIV**. Logo os valores ficam como abaixo:

**CSS EXEMPLO em REM**

```
  body {font: 100% verdana, arial, tahoma, sans-serif;}

    div {
        font-size: 1.88rem;
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 1.25rem;
    }

    p {
        font-size: 0.75rem;
    }
```

> Usamos sempre a base 16

**div: 30/16 = 1.88 

h1:  20/16 = 1.25 

P:   12/16= 0.75**

> Mas atenção que alguns navegadores podem não suportar esta medida

[Calculador da rem](https://offroadcode.com/rem-calculator/)
[Calculador da em](http://pxtoem.com/)
[Recomendações do uso de unidades em CSS](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.pt_BR.html#units)

Answer (score 3):

Isso se da porque `em` é uma unidade de medida de distância relativa

**Medidas relativas**

Para fontes: unidades `em`, `ex`, `ch`, `rem`
Porcentagem da viewport: unidades `vw`, `vh`, `vmin`, `vmax`
A especificação do W3C classifica tecnicamente a porcentagem (%) como tipo de dado e não unidade de medida.

*São baseadas em outras medidas, ou seja dependendo do dispositivo ela muda*

**Medidas absolutas**

Unidades `cm`, `mm`, `q`, `in`, `pt`, `pc`, `px`

*Sempre estáticas independente do dispositivo e referência*